# java serialization problems with different JVMs

Tags: java, android, serialization

I am having trouble using serialization in Java. I've searched the web for a solution but haven't found an answer yet.

The problem is this - I have a Java library (I have the code and I export it to an archive prior to executing the code) which I need to use with two differents JVMs. One JVM is on the server (Ubuntu, running Java(TM) JRE SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_09-b05)) and the other on Android 2.3.3. I compiled the library in Java 1.6.

Now, I am trying to import to the client, an object exported from the server, but I receive this error:

> java.io.InvalidClassException:
>   [Lweka.classifiers.functions.MultilayerPerceptron$NeuralEnd;;
>   Incompatible class (SUID):
>   [Lweka.classifiers.functions.MultilayerPerceptron$NeuralEnd;: static
>   final long serialVersionUID =-359311387972759020L; but expected
>   [Lweka.classifiers.functions.MultilayerPerceptron$NeuralEnd;: static
>   final long serialVersionUID =1920571045915494592L;

I do have an explicit serial version UID declared on the class `MultilayerPerceptron$NeuralEnd`, like this:

```
protected class NeuralEnd extends NeuralConnection {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7305185603191183338L;
}
```

Where NeuralConnection implements the java.io.Serializable interface. If I do a ***serialver*** on `MultilayerPerceptron$NeuralEnd` I receive the serialVersionUID which I declared. So, why have both JVMs changed this value? Can you help me?

Thanks,
Alberto

Comment: Please include the definition of your outer class as well.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand: the MultilayerPerceptron class?

Comment: Yes, because your inner class is not static, it contains an implicit reference to its outer class which must be Serializable. I'm curious to see your definition of the outer class (MultilayerPerceptron)

Comment: the class is this:  
public class MultilayerPerceptron 
  extends Classifier 
  implements OptionHandler, WeightedInstancesHandler, Randomizable {
  
  /** for serialization */
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -5990607817048210779L;

Comment: I didn't remember to say that Classifier implements Serializable :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution in my opinion. Serialization does not work between different JVM version (Dalvik is not even JVM...). Look for other solution like JSON/XML object serialization.

Comment: Not only is there a solution, it is practically given in the error message. Serialization between JVM versions has been working for over 15 years.

Answer (score 0):

Your serialVersionUID value is wrong. Set it to the 'expected' value in the error message.

Comment: Hi, it does not change anything: now the definition is  
protected class NeuralEnd extends NeuralConnection { static final long serialVersionUID = 1920571045915494592L; but I allways receive the same error

Comment: @Alberto Then you haven't deployed the modified class correctly.